# Добавить функцию поиска по назван

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Помогите как реализовать тут поиск за названием материала на складе либо какой-то другой способ поиска.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

class Stock
{
public:
    
    string name;
    double weight;
    double price;
    int quantity;

    Stock(string n, double w, double p, int q)
    {
        
        this->name = n;
        this->weight = w;
        this->price = p;
        this->quantity = q;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Матеріал на складi:" << endl;
        cout << "   Назва: " << name << endl;
        cout << "   Вага: " << weight << " кг" << endl;
        cout << "   Цiна: " << price << " грн" << endl;
        cout << "   Кiлькiсть: " << quantity << endl;

    }
};

void print(vector<Stock*> v) {
    system("cls");
    cout << "Список товарiв:" << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        v[i]->print();
    }
    system("pause");
}


Stock* add() {
    system("cls");
    string name;
    int quantity;
    double price;
    double weight;

    cout << "Введiть назву товару: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Введiть вагу товару: ";
    cin >> weight;
    cout << "Введiть цiну товару: ";
    cin >> price;
    cout << "Введiть кiлькiсть товару: ";
    cin >> quantity;
    return new Stock(name, weight, price, quantity);
}


void delete_Stock(vector<Stock*>* v)
{
    system("cls");
    int i;
    
        cout << "Введiть iндекс [0;" << v->size() - 1 << "] елемента, який треба видалити: ";
        cin >> i;
        if (i >= 0 && i < v->size())
        {
            v->erase(v->begin() + i);
        }
        
        else {
            cout << "Некоректне введення" << endl;
            system("pause");
        }

    
}



int main() {

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    vector<Stock*> v;

    int choise;
    do {
        system("cls");
        cout << "[1] Додавання" << endl;
        cout << "[2] Видалення" << endl;
        cout << "[3] Виведення iнформацiї на екран" << endl;
        cout << "[4] Вихiд" << endl;
        cin >> choise;

        switch (choise)
        {
        case 1:
            
            v.push_back(add());
            break;
        case 2:
            
            delete_Stock(&v);
            break;
        case 3:
            print(v);
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
        default:
            cout << "Некоректне введення" << endl;
            break;
        }

    } while (choise != 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по тому как ты задал вопрос сделал это

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Stock
{
private:
    string name;
    double weight;
    double price;
    int quantity;
public:

    Stock(string n, double w, double p, int q) {
        this->name = n;
        this->weight = w;
        this->price = p;
        this->quantity = q;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "Матеріал на складi:" << endl;
        cout << "   Назва: " << name << endl;
        cout << "   Вага: " << weight << " кг" << endl;
        cout << "   Цiна: " << price << " грн" << endl;
        cout << "   Кiлькiсть: " << quantity << endl;
    }

    string getName() const {
        return this->name;
    }

    double getWeight() const {
        return weight;
    }

    double getPrice() const {
        return price;
    }

    int getQuantity() const {
        return quantity;
    }
};

void print(vector<Stock*> v) {
    system("cls");
    cout << "Список товарiв:" << endl;
    for (auto & i : v) {
        i->print();
    }
    system("pause");
}


Stock* add() {
    //system("cls");
    string name;
    int quantity;
    double price;
    double weight;

    cout << "Введiть назву товару: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Введiть вагу товару: ";
    cin >> weight;
    cout << "Введiть цiну товару: ";
    cin >> price;
    cout << "Введiть кiлькiсть товару: ";
    cin >> quantity;
    return new Stock(name, weight, price, quantity);
}


void delete_Stock(vector<Stock*>* v)
{
    //system("cls");
    int i;

    cout << "Введiть iндекс [0;" << v->size() - 1 << "] елемента, який треба видалити: ";
    cin >> i;
    if (i >= 0 && i < v->size())
    {
        v->erase(v->begin() + i);
    }

    else {
        cout << "Некоректне введення" << endl;
       // system("pause");
    }
}

void search_by_name(const vector<Stock*>& v, const string& name) {
    for (auto element : v) {
        if (element->getName() == name)
            cout << element->getName() << " " << element->getWeight() << " "
            << element->getPrice() << " " << element->getQuantity()  << endl;
    }
}


int main() {
    vector<Stock*> v;

    int choise;
    do {
        //system("cls");
        cout << "[1] Додавання" << endl;
        cout << "[2] Видалення" << endl;
        cout << "[3] Виведення iнформацiї на екран" << endl;
        cout << "[5] Вихiд" << endl;
        cin >> choise;

        switch (choise)
        {
            case 1:
                v.push_back(add());
                break;
            case 2:

                delete_Stock(&v);
                break;
            case 3:
                print(v);
                break;
            case 4: {
                string name;
                cin >> name;
                search_by_name(v, name);
                break;
            }
            default:
                cout << "Некоректне введення" << endl;
                break;
        }

    } while (choise != 5);
}
```